# Alternate for ABAddressBookRegisterExternalChangeCallback

Tags: ios, objective-c, abaddressbook

As ABAddressBookRegisterExternalChangeCallback is deprecated in iOS 9.0 and later. Is there any alternative avaiable for getting contact change or if a new contact is added in the address book. Please provide the implementation if possible in objective-c.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything in the `AddressBook.framework` has been deprecated in iOS 9. Apple wants you to use the `Contacts.framework` instead. Specifically, look at `CNContactStoreDidChangeNotification` defined in `CNContactStore`.

Comment: Can you please provide me with a sample implementation. I am new to iOS. If link on github is available please provide that.

Comment: This tutorial covers the basics: http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ios-9-an-introduction-to-the-contacts-framework--cms-25599