# ABAddressBookRegisterExternalChangeCallback how to implement in swift

Tags: ios, swift

```
ABAddressBookRegisterExternalChangeCallback(addressBookRef, { _, _, _ in self.addressBookDidChange()}, nil)
```

but have this warning

> A C function pointer cannot be formed from a closure that captures context

how I can resolve this only with Swift?!

Comment: Note that the function is deprecated as of iOS 9, compare https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39103732/alternate-for-abaddressbookregisterexternalchangecallback.

Comment: is deprecated if min iOS version is 9, but it's not true. I want to support iOS 8. `CNContactStoreDidChangeNotification ` - not work on iOS 8